# Django test runner not running with non-standard project structure

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I've got a Django project with a slightly non-standard structure (shown below) and the Django test runner isn't working.

```
root_dir
  ├ src
  |  ├ myapp_dir (apps.py, etc.)
  |  ├ project_files_dir (settings.py, wsgi.py, etc.)
  |  ├ utils_dir, etc.
  |  └ manage.py
  ├ tests
  |  ├ test_settings.py
  |  └ myapp_tests_dir (tests1.py, tests2.py, etc.)
  ├ setup.py
  └ runtests.py
```

`apps.py` contains:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'
```

`settings.py` includes `INSTALLED_APPS = [..., myapp]`

`test_settings.py` includes `INSTALLED_APPS = [..., myapp, tests]`

`setup.py` contains:
    from os.path import dirname, join

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

root = dirname(__file__)

with open(join(root, "README.md")) as readme:
    README = readme.read()

try:
    with open(join(root, "VERSION")) as version_file:
        version = version_file.read().strip()
except IOError:
    version = "0.0.1"

setup(
    name="myapp-name",
    version=version,
    packages=find_packages("src"),
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    include_package_data=True,
    description="MyApp description",
    long_description=README,
    author="My Name",
    author_email="my@email.com",
    url="https://",
    install_requires=["celery", "django", "requests"],
)
```

`runtests.py` contains:

```
import os
import sys

import django
from django.conf import settings
from django.test.utils import get_runner

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'tests.test_settings'
    django.setup()
    TestRunner = get_runner(settings)
    test_runner = TestRunner()
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(["tests"])
    sys.exit(bool(failures))
```

When I to run the tests with `python runtests.py` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp'`

If try to change `test_settings.py` to include `INSTALLED_APPS = [..., src.myapp, tests]` I then get `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'myapp'. Check that 'src.myapp.apps.MyAppConfig.name' is correct.`

It's probably also worth mentioning that `runserver` runs fine from the working directory `root_dir` when calling it like this:

```
> python src/manage.py runserver

Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 22, 2020 - 16:06:19
Django version 3.0.5, using settings 'project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C
```

Comment: did you add it to your installed_apps ? remember each folder its basically an app. make sure you have __init__.py so python can read the folder... test_app/__init__.py

Comment: Yes, I already mentioned this in the question. And if I hadn't done it, Django runserver wouldn't run.